# How to convert base64 string of an image to an uploadable file without writing it to a filesystem

Tags: node.js

I have a variable in my NodeJS application which contains base64 string of an image. I need to send a form to some server with POST request containing this image. The problem is I can't convert base64 string to an image without writing it to a filesystem. Here's my code:

```
const imagePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../images/anomalies/' + Date.now() + '.png')
fs.writeFileSync(imagePath, img, { encoding: 'base64' })

setTimeout(() => {
    fs.unlinkSync(imagePath)
}, 30_000)

const form = new FormData()
form.append('photo', fs.createReadStream(imagePath))
```

As you can see, I need to write base64 string to a file and then grab it with `fs.createReadStream`. Otherwise file won't upload. I tried converting it to ReadStream via [stream-buffers](https://github.com/samcday/node-stream-buffer) (but server still not accepted that data) and also I tried to make a Blob from it but Node don't have blobs and all these modules on npm are either too old or don't have typings which is not great at all. I also tried `Buffer.from(base64, 'base64')`, which doesn't work as well.

Is there any way to create an uplodable image file from base64 encoded string without accessing filesystem in NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing it to a Buffer

```
const encodedData = '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'

const buff = Buffer.from(encodedData, 'base64');
```

Then you can use form data

```
let data = new FormData();
  data.append('files', buff, `image.jpg`);
```

And for the project I'm working on I was using Axios to send the file.

```
  let config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/upload',
    data: data,
  };

  const response = await axios.request(config);
```

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to convert the Buffer object returned by `fs.readFileSync` to a base64 string

```
const base64Image = fs.readFileSync(imagePath).toString('base64')
```